# Can I provide default "context" to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

**Background:**

The second "context" argument to the jQuery selector call (e.g: `jQuery(selector, context)`) can be provided to give the selector engine a starting point from which to descend.

This is often useful if you need to control content in an IFRAME (in the same domain). You simply pass `iframe.contentWindow.document` as the "context" argument.

If any JavaScript code is loaded in the IFRAME which makes use of jQuery, and is **CALLED FROM THE SCOPE OF THE OUTER WINDOW**, then any reference to `$` or `jQuery` in that code will actually be the instance of `jQuery` from the outer window.

The problem comes when that JavaScript code in the IFRAME (say Bootstrap.js) does something like `$(document)` (or does some other selector without a "context" argument). When that code (defined inside the iframe) is called from the outer window, `document` refers to the HTMLDocument element from the outer window - which is usually not the desired outcome.

**Question:**

It would be super useful to be able to create a lexically-scoped copy/wrapper of jQuery that has a default "context" argument, provided by whomever creates it.

Example:

```
// jQuery already exists out here
var iframe = document.createElement('IFRAME');
iframe.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    // code in here can already refer to $ for 'outer' jQuery

    // code in here can refer to $local for 'inner' jQuery by virtue of...
    var $local = jQueryWithContext($, iframe.contentWindow.document);

    // code loaded with IFRAME will use $local by virtue of ...
    iframe.contentWindow.jQuery = iframe.contentWindow.$ = $local;

});
iframe.src = '/path/to/iframe/content.html';
```

The question is, is it possible to write something like `jQueryWithContext` above?

**Why?**

Sometimes you want to isolate 3rd party HTML components which (while you trust them from a security perspective) are misbehaved from a CSS / JavaScript pollution perspective.

Bootstrap.js is a good example. It calls `$(document)` a fair bit, and does other similar context-less selector calls. If jQuery could be re-scoped in the way I describe, then this 'not optimally' written libraries could be isolated quite easily.

Additionally, it can be very helpful to use the same `$.data(el, ...)` collection from both frames, and this is quite tricky without some context management.

Comment: Why isn't the iframe loading jQuery itself and using its own jQuery object?

Comment: It could, certainly. But then you'd need to create bi-directional plumbing in both windows to call back and forth. Than makes it harder to simply sub-frame existing HTML+JS content. Also, $.data is different for each of the jQuery instances, and that may not be desirable.

Comment: Hm. So is the inner frame using the outer frame's jQuery, or is the outer frame using the inner frame's jQuery? If so, why? An explicit interaction API seems more appropriate here, since it's less fragile (doesn't assume the other page has jQuery or that its DOM is exactly what we expect), is often more readable to other developers, and avoids these issues entirely. (Granted, that's with the limited information I have…)

Comment: Inner frame using outer frame's jQuery (overriding the inner frame's jQuery if one is present). All very good points on fragility, etc. I guess sometimes I'd just like to 'sub-frame' some content without thinking too hard about it. :-) If I really need decent bi-directional orchestration, I can always code it, but I don't like paying the penalty by default. :-/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it would be rather simple:

```
function jQueryWithContext( selector, context ) {
  // I added the possibility to overwrite the context here, but you could delete
  return $( selector, context || iframe.contentWindow.document );
}
jQueryWithContext( '#main' ).show();
```

But to force it to plugins, you'd probably need to go like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict(); // keep the real jQuery for now
$ = function( selector, context ){
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context || iframe.contentWindow.document );
};
$.fn = $.prototype = jQuery.fn;
jQuery.extend( $, jQuery ); // copy static method
// Then override default jQuery
jQuery = $;
```

This kinda work, but it could break some usage of `$()` (Maybe not now, but it's possible in future jQuery version, or anytime the presence of a `context` parameter break the normal behavior).

Comment: jQuery has a bunch of other methods which you can call with $.something (rather than a selector call). If those methods make selector calls (internally) without content, this might be a limited approach. Do you think this might be the case?

Comment: Well, that's why I renamed the function to something else than `$`, so actual code won't break. But you'd like to force this default context as being `$`; so that plugins would use it seamlessly?

Comment: Yes (for plugins). I guess my real question is, does jQuery internally make selector calls from within non-selector methods? If so, those would also need to be patched.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: If at all then only relative to the current selection I guess, so those should not be a problem.

Comment: I added what seems to me like a solution to overwriting the default jQuery. (Haven't tested thoroughly)

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Thanks. I'll do a lot more testing. Perhaps if there are further issues, patching jQuery itself might be easier.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias: That's very cool using jQuery to extend itself! :-)