# What is the default context when using jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

According to [the jQuery DOC](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/), a `context` can be specified when selecting an element.

I usually use it when I make AJAX requests:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function(data){
        var id = $("#my_id", data);
        }
    })
```

And if I want to search in the current DOM, I just write `$("#my_id")`.

Now, I want to create a function which takes as argument the `context`, in order to search through DOM or AJAX response.

```
function my_func(context) {
    var id = $("#my_id", context);
}
```

What should I pass as `context` if I want to search through the current DOM?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964827/can-i-provide-default-context-to-jquery

Comment: why not just only include the context if one is passed?

Comment: @Mathletics In this case, I should specify in the body of my method `if (argument) {$("#my_id", argument)} else {$("#my_id")}` whenever I use jQuery...

Comment: If you check source code you will see that jQuery uses `document` as default context.

Comment: A better default would be `undefined`, otherwise it will do `$(document).find('#myid')` instead of `$('#myid')`

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if you are using an id, there should only be one element with that id anyway.  Does changing the context really make a difference?

Comment: This seems like a really unnecessary abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about passing in the global DOM context then you shouldn't have to pass anything. `context` will default to `undefined` and passed into the jQuery selector (which is the same value it would have if you just called `$("#my_id")`)

Comment: "context will default to undefined" -- Source? Is it `undefined` or is it `document`?

Comment: It's standard JS behavior when an argument isn't passed. The value defaults to `undefined`. This means jQuery will default to using the `document` context (which is what it does if you don't pass a context) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107823/what-happens-if-i-dont-pass-a-parameter-is-a-javascript-function

Comment: And when jQuery utilizes `context` is it still `undefined`? I think the real question here is: **"What does the jQuery constructor *use* as the default?**